# How to reinstall OSX from single user mode?

Tags: macos, software

Running macOS High Sierra (iMac mid-2011 21.5 inch), stuck in boot-loop, white screen at Recovery and Internet Recovery.

I do not have access to another Mac nor USB boot.

I can boot in to SingleUserMode.

How do I reinstall macOS from SingleUserMode which may fix the problem?

I contacted Apple a few weeks ago and they suggested that it may be a hardware problem (they weren't specific as far as I remember, I can't find the conversation email) and suggested a local repair shop because they do not carry parts for old computers.

I ran diagnostic test and it says it is not a hardware problem. Then I asked a local repair shop: it is not the hardware.

Then I contacted apple again and told them it is not hardware problem, what can I do? They suggested going to a nearby technician (Apple authorized).

Not willing to spend money on it.

Comment: What make and year?

Comment: @JBis Sorry I forgot; updated.

Comment: Normally not possible since Single user mode disables many of the system demons and processes needed to run an update. However you could try to repair your disk with fschk

Comment: @Buscar웃 Ah I tried that but it didn't help. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: You say Apple won't offer services... I've never known them to refuse to put a fresh OS on any machine you take to the Apple Store [for free], no matter what the age.

Comment: @Tetsujin I contacted but they said it is hardware and they dont offer (which is what I meant, sorry for being unclear). I contacted them now, and well they suggest a technician. Thought it would be costly, thanks for letting me know though.

Comment: That rather makes the entire question unclear; whether or not it is actually a hardware issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin They first said it was hardware (week or two ago when i contacted) and suggested to get it fixed from local repair shop (they dont carry parts for vintage, obsolete products). Afterwards I learned about diagnostics test and it said no hardware problems. I consulted local repair shop and they said no hardware problem (but were charging a lot for repairing). I contacted apple again and they suggested apple authorized technicians near me, but I avoided it and came here to see if there was any way I could do it myself (my parents dont want to waste money on it now).

Comment: @Tetsujin I thought it cost to just make apple look at it, but thanks for the info. above. I could probably convince parents now. But if there is anything I could do with single-user mode (other than making backup), that would be great...

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200113

Comment: You'll have to leave SingleUserMode. In that mode you willnot get far enough to install anything. If the AppleStore diagnosed a HW problem: what did they say it was? (That diagnosis may be in error. Further you may carry a USB stick into the store and get a proper installer onto that if it indeed is still just a bitched SW install). But if it is HW, then please share the diagnosis the Apple guys gave with an [edit].

Comment: @LangLangC Updated. Oh my mac does not support usb install, is it possible to use a non-apple external dvd drive and an installer disc to do it? I will try to get hold of an other mac, thank you Buscar옷 and LangC

Comment: A month late but, it turned out to be a hardware problem. One of the *technicians* managed to damage my motherboard increasing the costs. Main problem was the graphics card, and power supply. The ps probably caused damage to graphics card.